# Prove that if $k\mid n$ then $p(A_k)={1\over k}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $n$ be a natural number, $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot...\cdotp_m^{a_m}$. Let us randomly choose a number between 1 and $n$ with a uniform, equal chance. Let us denote the event "The number chosen is divisible by k" as $A_k$, where $1\le k\le n$. Prove that if $k\mid n$ then $p(A_k)={1\over k}$.

I tried many things. Tried to work with the prime factorization, but I wouldn't get the required result. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=ak$ there are are exactly $a$ numbers between $1$ and $n$ divisible by $k$ which are :
$$k,2k,3k,\cdots,ak $$ and there are $n$ numbers in total so:
$$p(A_k)=\frac{a}{n}=\frac{1}{k} $$

Comment: So simple. How could I have not seen it?
I was looking at primes too much.

Comment: sometimes we all do look in the wrong direction

Answer (score 1):

Let us list the elements from $1$ to $n$ divisible by $k$. We have the set $A_k$ to be
$$A_k = \left\{k,2k,3k,\ldots,\left\lfloor{\dfrac{n}k}\right\rfloor k \right\}$$
and the total set to be $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Hence, the probability of a number being divisible by $k$ is
$$p = \dfrac{\vert A_k \vert}{\vert A \vert} = \dfrac1n \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}k\right\rfloor$$
Since we are given that $k$ divides $n$, we obtain the desired probability to be $\dfrac1k$.